# signature request message unreadable

Tags: metamask, signature, eip

so reading [EIP-712](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbNUU.png), it says

> Currently signed messages are an opaque hex string displayed to the user with little context about the items that make up the message.

[image]

but isn't this wrong? because i see messages can be in string format where it's readable.
[image]

what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) was started in 2017 and since then it has evolved. For example Metamask's [signing API](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#signing-data-with-metamask) has several iterations to make it more usable and secure.